# How to install libmicrohttpd10 in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, kodi

Ubuntu 17.10 contains libmicrohttpd12 but I also need libmicrohttpd10 for kodi.
Can I have both ?

Comment: Why does kodi not like libmicrohttpd12?

Answer (score 3):

It is available in 16.04, and installing the 16.04 version on 17.10 is likely to work (assuming you really cannot install 16.04; otherwise you should do that). However, **do not** just download a `.deb` and install it, because if a vulnerability is found in it, you will not automatically get the fix. Instead, you can add the 16.04 repositories as follows.

First, copy your current `sources.list` to a new file in `/etc/sources.list.d`:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial_for_libmicrohttpd10.list
```

The name of the new file is just a reminder for the future you of what its purpose is. You can also add a more elaborate comment in it.

Second, use your text editor of choice to replace all occurrences of `artful` in the file to `xenial`. For example:

```
printf ',s/artful/xenial/\nw\n' | sudo ed /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial_for_libmicrohttpd10.list
```

Finally, just to be sure that no Xenial package other than `libmicrohttpd10` will be accidentally installed, give them a low priority by creating a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` like this:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=xenial
Pin-Priority: 99

Package: libmicrohttpd10
Pin: release n=xenial
Pin-Priority: 500
```

Then you can do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libmicrohttpd10`.

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's/artful/xenial/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial_for_libmicrohttpd10.list` seems simpler. Also, maybe consider adding only the `universe` repo.

Comment: @muru I don't like `sed -i` because it is [non-standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) (there is a joke: using `sed -i` is like alcohol-free beer, it tastes the same but you know it ain't right!). Adding only `universe` could be problematic if a dependency from `main` is needed (it is not currently the case since all the dependencies are in Artful, but some could be removed further down the line if their sonumber increases).

Comment: It maybe non-standard for POSIX, but it's perfectly fine for GNU, and hence Ubuntu.

Comment: @muru I know that; what is your point? I said why I did not include it in my answer; I never said it does not work.

Comment: That your reason isn't much of a reason, after all, you stopped being POSIX only when you used sudo, so POSIX clearly doesn't matter.

Comment: @muru What you think about my reason (for choosing one particular example) matters how?

Comment: you're the one who asked what my point was, if it didn't matter, don't ask. End of discussion.